# Centralizer/normalizer of degree $n$ extension embedded in $\mathrm{GL}_n(k)$

Tags: matrices, group-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields

Let $k$ be a finite field, and let $\ell/k$ be the unique degree $n$ extension of $k$. Then, by choosing a basis for $\ell$, we can identify $\ell^\times$ with a subgroup of $G=\mathrm{GL}_n(k)$. Such an embedding is uniquely determined up to conjugacy, so we may ask:

**Question:** What is the centralizer/normalizer of $\ell^\times\subset G$?

A couple of observations:

- For each $g\in N_G(\ell^\times)$, the conjugation action $g-g^{-1}\colon\ell\to\ell$ fixes the subfield $k$ (since $Z(G)=k^\times$), so there is a homomorphism $N_G(\ell^\times)/C_G(\ell^\times)\to\mathrm{Gal}(\ell/k)$. Moreover, this is surjective, since if $\ell=k(\alpha)$ and $\sigma\in\mathrm{Gal}(\ell/k)$ is the generator, then $\alpha,\sigma(\alpha)\in G$ are conjugate (they are clearly conjugate over $\ell$).
- If $g\in C_G(\ell^\times)$, then $\ell[g]\supset\ell$ is a commutative algebra. Maybe exploring properties of this algebra tells us something??
- When $\ell/k$ is quadratic and $k$ has characteristic $>2$, then $\ell=k(\sqrt a)$ for some $a\in k$, so $\ell^\times$ can be identified with
  $$\{uI_2+v\begin{pmatrix}&a\\1&\end{pmatrix}:u,v\in k,(u,v)\ne(0,0)\}.$$
  Now, by direct computation, we see that $C_G(\ell^\times)=\ell^\times$, but $\begin{pmatrix}-1&\\&1\end{pmatrix}\in N_G(\ell^\times)$ corresponds to the generator of the Galois group of $\ell/k$.

In general, I believe $C_G(\ell^\times)=\ell^\times$, and $N_G(\ell^\times)$ is some $C_n$-extension, but I cannot prove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The centralizer $C_G(\ell^\times)$ consists of the $\ell$-linear maps in $G = GL_n(k)$. Since $\ell = k^n$ has dimension $1$ as a $\ell$-vector space, you get $C_G(\ell) = \ell^\times$.

The normalizer $N_G(\ell^\times)$ acts on $\ell$ by conjugation, and $N_G(\ell^\times)/C_G(\ell^\times)$ embeds into $Gal(\ell/k) \cong C_n$.

Say $|k| = q$. The Frobenius map $\sigma: \ell \rightarrow \ell$, $\sigma(x) = x^q$ is $k$-linear so $\sigma \in N_G(\ell^\times)$. Then $N_G(\ell^\times)$ is a semidirect product of $\ell^\times$ and $\langle \sigma \rangle$.

This particular group is sometimes denoted $\Gamma L_1(q^n)$.

Comment: Oh of course! Thank you! This is completely obvious in hindsight...

Comment: Wonderful! To think that I would myself have called upon Skolem-Noether to ascertain that the Frobenius automorphism comes from conjugation by a suitable matrix :-)